# Calling inject() from a Dagger Module method - bad practice?

Tags: android, mvp, dagger

I'm still new to Dependency Injection and I try to implement my application using the **MVP** design pattern. I use a **scoped graph** for each view. I decided that my Adapter should be considered part of the View after reading through [this great article](http://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/).

The view in my example case is a **Fragment**. I created a module [referred to as **FragmentModule**] which  provide its **Presenter** and **View**.

Before I started to mess around, the module only injected the **Fragment** and it provided the **FragmentAdapter** by calling its constructor with the required parameters.

Module:

```
@Module(
        overrides = true,
        includes = BaseFragmentModule.class,
        injects = {
                MyFragment.class,
        }
)
public class FragmentModule {

    private MyFragment mFragment;

    // ... // Other methods removed for clarity

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public FragmentAdapter provideAdapter() {
        return new FragmentAdapter(mFragment.getActivity(), mFragment);
    }

    // ... //
}
```

The **FragmentAdapter** constructor looked somewhat like this:

```
private Context mContext;
private CustomListener mListener;

public FragmentAdapter(Context context, CustomListener listener)
{
    mContext = context;
    mListener = listener;
    // ... // 
}
```

This might still be "the correct way to do it" but I want to discuss the way I'm currently doing it, so keep on reading!

Then I rewrote it again, so that the **FragmentAdapter** took a reference to the **Fragment** instance. I then assigned Context and Listener within the **FragmentAdapter** constructor.

```
private MyFragment mFragment;

@Provides
@Singleton
public FragmentAdapter provideAdapter() {
    return new FragmentAdapter(mFragment);
}
```

The Adapter constructor looked like this:

```
private Context mContext;
private CustomListener mListener;

public FragmentAdapter(MyFragment iFragment)
{
    mContext = iFragment.getActivity();
    mListener = iFragment;
    // ... // 
}
```

After that I decided that I wanted to inject the Context to the adapter for some reason. So I continued:
I made the **FragmentModule** inject also the Adapter, like so:

```
@Module(
        overrides = true,
        includes = BaseFragmentModule.class,
        injects = {
                FragmentAdapter.class,
                MyFragment.class,
        }
)
```

Now I had to learn how to inject the **FragmentAdapter** to the Fragment's scoped ObjectGraph in a nice, clean way. First I called **inject()** from the **FragmentAdapter** constructor:

**FragmentModule:**

```
// ... //
private MyFragment mFragment;
// ... //
@Provides
@Singleton
public FragmentAdapter provideAdapter() {
    return new FragmentAdapter(mFragment);
}
// ... //
```

**FragmentAdapter**:

```
@Inject Context mContext;
@Inject MyListener mListener;

public FragmentAdapter(MyFragment iFragment)
{
    iFragment.getObjectGraph().inject(this);
    // ... // 
}
```

Again, for some reason (remember I am learning..) - I wanted to get the injection to work without having to pass the **Fragment** instance to the **FragmentAdapter** constructor, so I ended up  calling **inject()** from within the Module class:

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public FragmentAdapter provideAdapter() {
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter();
            mFragment.getObjectGraph().inject(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.initialize(); // Code moved from constructor which depends on injected members
        }
        return mAdapter;
    }
```

Now I am curious - what do you consider to be the best practice here? How would you implement the Adapter and Fragment dependencies with Dagger injection? And why?

Thanks a lot for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, `ObjectGraph.inject(...)` should be avoided as much as possible. Instead, you want to do Constructor Injection: pass your injected dependencies in your constructor.

You can do this by adding an `@Inject` annotation to you constructor:

```
private final Context mContext;
private final MyListener mListener;

@Inject
public FragmentAdapter(Context context, MyListener listener)
{
    mContext = context;
    mListener = listener;
    // ... // 
}
```

Now, you don't need the `provideAdapter()` anymore, since Dagger recognizes the `@Inject` annotation on the constructor. You do need to provide `Context` and `MyListener` instances, which I believe you are already doing.

That having said, I don't believe `MyListener` should be injected. It is not a dependency of your `FragmentAdapter`, but a feature. Just call `setListener(MyListener)` from your `Fragment` class.

A final remark, sometimes `inject(...)` cannot be avoided. Especially when you're using classes whose constructors you don't manage (such as `Activity` and `Fragment`).

Comment: Thanks for your input Niek! I have settled with constructor injection. I agree with your remark - in fact I ended up removing the interfaces previously used and I handle the events directly in the adapter - since I consider it part of the View anyway. Right or wrong.. It's an expandable listview.